# SUMPRODUCT and IF conditional (LibreOffice)

Tags: libreoffice, worksheet-function, conditional-statements

I would like to multiply two cells in a same row, if a condition of a third adjacent cell is met; then sum the result to the next product in the next row (if condition is met), and so on.

```
   | A | B | C |
---|---|---|---|
 1 |   |   |   |
 2 |   |   |   |
 3 |   |   |   |
 4 |   |   |   |
```

Something like this:

```
Loop (from i = 1 to i = 4)
    if (Ci == "Some text")
        sum += (Ai * Bi)
```

I have tried with this formula, which doesn't work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4, B1:B4, IF(C1:C4="Some text", 1, 0))
```

And this, which gives me <s>some incorrect sum</s>. **EDIT:** It *does* work, I was blind.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4, B1:B4, C1:C4="Some text")
```

What am I doing wrong, and how should I proceed?

---

**EDIT**: Now I see that the conditional `=IF(test, then_value, otherwise_value)` doesn't seam to accept a range for the test value.
So, how can this be archived?

**EDIT 2**: I was blind. Indeed, this works:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4, B1:B4, C1:C4="Some text")
```

Comment: No question was to come of this

Comment: This stuff works indeed and I really needed today, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was blind, this does indeed work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4, B1:B4, C1:C4="Some text")
```